# django migration No migrations to apply

Tags: django, migration

I have screwed up my database so I tried to redo it. I did:

1) deleted all tables via sql

2) deleted the migrations folder

So when I now do `manage.py makemigrations myapp` it is creating the migration folder and the initial.py file, which looks fine. Also the `__init__.py` is there. However, if i do `manage.py makemigrations myapp` I always get the message "No migrations to apply."

I looked up the database in the shell and the tables are not there.

I am using Django 1.8.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Django keeps track of all the applied migrations in `django_migrations` table.
So just delete all the rows in the `django_migrations` table that are related to you app like:

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='your-app-name';
```

and then do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for `Django keeps track of all the applied migrations in django_migrations table.`, but  `just delete all the rows in the django_migrations table that are related to you app like` is very destructive

Answer (score 0):

Django keeps track of all the applied migrations in django_migrations table.

So, you can follow this method:

1. Delete the related rows from django_migrations.
2. run python manage.py migrate.

Answer (score 0):

I usually ran into that issue myself. Here is the workaround I found:

Replace your database sqlite3 with this

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '<your_username>$<your_database_name>',
    'USER': '<your_username>',
    'PASSWORD': '<your_mysql_password>',
    'HOST': '<your_mysql_hostname>',
}
```

}`

The fill in for  can be found in the databases tab on your Pythonanywhere dashboard.

Push it to github from your Terminal and pull it down from Pythonanywhere Bash again. You may have to add this on Bash Console: pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

As @Anush mentioned, Django does keep track of all of the migrations in the `django_migrations` table. As mentioned, you can use raw SQL to remove the migration row to reset Django's migration history for the concerned app.

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='my-app';
```

If you are uncomfortable deleting rows like this, then you can use Django's management command replacing `my-app` for the name of your app.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake my-app zero
```

That command will remove the migration history rows from the database leaving you to start your migration again from scratch. You will then need to:

- Delete all of the migration files within your app's 'migrations' directory but ensure that the `__init__.py` file remains.
- Ensure that your app's data models are set up as you need them
- Make the migrations again with the command `python manage.py makemigrations {your_app_name}`. This will create the `0001_initial.py` file within your app's migrations directory.
- You will not be able to actually migrate the initial database migration because the database table already exists, so you will need to fake the migration with the command, `python manage.py migrate my_app --fake-initial`

Answer (score 0):

After running into this problem on Django 3.0 I spent an entire day troubleshooting this. Sharing this so that others would not need to. Most of the times running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Should solve the problem. I followed the above step after deleting the files in migrations folder (except **init**.py), however I was not able to solve the problem. I found that every time you run makemigrations, a python file called 000x_xxx.py is created in the migrations folder. I looked inside the file and found that all my required changes were there but it also had other create table operations that I did not need (i.e those tables had already been created). If you run migrate with --fake or --fake-initial, the whole execution will be faked (i.e executed without actually making any change in the database).

To solve the problem I opened the generated 0000x_xxx.py file and deleted the changes I wanted to make in the database and ran "python manage.py makemigrations" again. This created a new migration file with the changes I wanted. After that I ran the following command.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial appname
```

This solved the problem. Not sure if this should be this complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

just run:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many problems and require a solution

**Create a database backup (more than one if necessary)**

My solution was to run the following query in the SQL shell

```
drop database database_name with (force);
```

**This completely removes the database, be careful**

It solved the error for me

Greetings